# How to wait for a method call to finish before continuing

Tags: java, android, wait

I am trying to wait for a method call to finish before continuing on, but my attempt so far doesn't work.

```
public class SaveMyEntitiesToServerResolver {
    public void syncNewMyEntities() {
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            new MyAsyncJSONPostTaskService(mContext, postURL, jsonObject).myPostJSON(new IMyAsyncJSONPostTask() {
                @Override
                public void processFinishAsyncJSONPostTask(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject e;
                        try {
                            e = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                            synchronized (this) {
                                setMyEntityMetadataId(e.getJSONArray("_myEntityMetadataList"));
                                this.wait();
                                // Then do something else
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    synchronized void setMyEntityMetadataId(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject e;
            try {
                e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Long localMetadataId = Long.parseLong(e.getString("localMetadataId"));
                // Save localMetadataId to DB

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i == jsonArray.length() - 1) {
                this.notifyAll();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can I wait for a method call to finish before continuing?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: which method exactly?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using `notify` and `wait` at all. You're calling `setMyEntityMetadataId`, so you won't get to the `wait()` call until after the method has finished anyway. Note that you also won't call `notifyAll()`, as `i` is never equal to `jsonArray.length()`. There's no indication that you're doing things with multiple threads here. I suggest you just remove the `notifyAll` and `wait` parts of your code - if there are still problems then, please clarify the question.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko `setMyEntityMetadataId(e.getJSONArray("_myEntityMetadataList"));`

Comment: you don't need to wait it, it is synchronous

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry. `if (i == jsonArray.length() - 1)`, but still not working

Comment: Please read the rest of my comment. You're calling `wait` and `notifyAll` for no obvious reason - the code in `processFinishAsyncJSONPostTask` won't continue until `setMyEntityMetadataId` has finished anyway.

Comment: Can you write the orders that you need to call methods?

Comment: Also, beware of the possible NumberFormatException parsing the long.